# Read the output of `date` command into variable in C script Unix

Tags: string, date, unix, types, pipe

I have to store what `date` command (Unix) outputs, as a string into a variable, then write this to a pipe in a child process. In the end, output this in the father process, by using the pipe. This is what I have tried so far:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int channel[2];
    if(pipe(channel) == -1) { printf("Eroare la crearea pipe ului!\n"); return 1; }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0) { printf("Eroare la crearea procesului\n"); }
    else if(pid > 0)
    {
        wait(NULL);      // wait for the child to write to the pipe
        close(channel[1]); // close not-needed side of pipe

        char *aux;
        read(channel[0], aux, sizeof(channel[0]));

        printf("Sirul citit este: '%s'\n", aux);
        close(channel[0]);

    // exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        close(channel[0]);

        // char *data_acum = (char*)system("date");
        char *data_acum = system("date");
        printf("variabila `data_acum` are valoarea '%s'\n", data_acum);
        // printf(typeof(data_acum));
        write( channel[1], data_acum, sizeof(data_acum) );
        // write( channel[1], system("date"), sizeof(system("date")) );

    // exit(0);
    }

return 0;
}
```

**output**:

```
Thu Apr 30 02:05:39 EEST 2020
variabila `data_acum` are valoarea '(null)'
Sirul citit este: '1I^HHPTLz'
```

More specifically, my problem is:

I am trying to figure out why this line `char *data_acum = system("date")` or the commented one `//char *data_acum = (char*)system("date")` are not working; by "working", I am expecting to store the string that `date` would display if I were to use it directly in the command line. Does this `system("date")` not return a string that I can store in a variable of `type const char*` ?

Also, I am not 100% sure what the warning wants to say: `warning:initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`. I understand that there is some incompatibility between the types, but does `system("date")` actually return an `int` ? And thus I am improperly trying to somehow convert it to a `const char*` ? I recall seeing something about dates actually being hexadecimal numbers.

Sorry for, maybe, asking too many questions! In the end, to sum up my questions: **what does `system("date")` return and how can I fix my problem?**

**expected output**:

```
Thu Apr 30 02:05:39 EEST 2020
variabila `data_acum` are valoarea 'Thu Apr 30 02:05:39 EEST 2020'
Sirul citit este: 'Thu Apr 30 02:05:39 EEST 2020'
```

**Notes:**

1) I must use `date`

2) I did not check for the return status of the child on purpose

3) I know it is not good practice to use `wait(NULL)`.

Comment: Are you looking for [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)?

Comment: Hi! And thank you for commenting! No, not right now. I am restricted to use `date`. After I solve it with `date`, I will also try with `popen`. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't use just the `date` command from C. You need some kind of function to start it. Do you really mean that `system` is okay but `popen` isn't?

Comment: No, I do not mean that.

Comment: Then why did you use `system` in the code in your question?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand. Maybe provide me with code snippet? I do not know any other way of calling the function from within a C script, but I am pretty much sure that there is one, apart from anything related to popen. If that is what you were asking.

Comment: Hit Ctrl+F and type `system`. Note that part of your question will highlight.

Comment: I understood that :)). I was not asking you to provide me with **my** code snippet :)). I just did not see the link between using `system` in my code and `popen`.

Comment: In any case, thank you!

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica  as I have not managed to get it done, I would appreciate if you could provide me with the popen alternative

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica this is what I meant (added answer)I have resorted to using an auxiliary file. I simply could not get `date` 's output stored somewhere in a buffer somehow else, the without using `popen` ( I am a beginner ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my problem. I was looking for something similar to this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 105

int main()
{
    int channel[2];
    if(pipe(channel) == -1) { printf("Eroare la crearea pipe ului!\n"); return 1; }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0) { printf("Eroare la crearea procesului\n"); }
    else if(pid > 0)
    {

        close(channel[1]); // close pipe's writing end
//      wait(NULL); // wait for children to finish

        int status;
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);   // wait for children to finish
        int return_value = WEXITSTATUS(status);

        char aux[BUFFER_SIZE];
        read(channel[0], aux, BUFFER_SIZE);
        close(channel[0]); // close pipe's reading end

        printf("%s\n", aux);
    //exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        close(channel[0]); // inchid capatul de citire al pipe ului (in copil voi scrie in pipe)

        system("date >> temp.txt"); /* I have eventually used an auxiliary file to get the output of `date`
        command into it, then read it using f.
        */

        FILE * fptr = fopen("temp.txt", "r");
        if(fptr == NULL) { printf("eroare la crearea fisierului auxiliar\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fptr); // read date

        fclose(fptr); // close file
        remove("temp.txt"); // delete temporary file

        buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0'; // delete '\n' character from the end of read string (might need it without the '\n' later)
        write(channel[1], buffer, sizeof(buffer)); // scriu in capatul de scriere al pipe ului data citita
    exit(0); // succesfully leave child
    }

return 0;
}
```

Now I am going to try and implement the probably much more easier way, with using `popen`; also suggested by Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica.